# Contact Form with Custom Datepicker NMR don't validate field when required

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

Using [Custom Datepicker NMR](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-datepicker-nmr/) plugin with CF7 which nearly duplicate the CF7 date.php  module and add a new $tag where we can use jquery-ui-datepicker.

Everything works as except but when the field is required, the validation do not validate the datepicker field on form submit.

Looks like this line have no effect :

```
 **$atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';**
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance

[PHP]

```
add_action('wpcf7_init', 'nmr_add_jqueryui_datepicker');
function nmr_add_jqueryui_datepicker()
{
    wpcf7_add_form_tag(
        array('datepicker', 'datepicker*'),
        'nmr_datepicker_form_tag_handler',
        array('name-attr' => true)
    );
}

function nmr_datepicker_form_tag_handler($tag)
{
    if (empty($tag->name)) {
        return '';
    }
    $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error($tag->name);

    $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class($tag->type);

    $class .= ' wpcf7-validates-as-date';

    if ($validation_error) {
        $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';
    }

    $atts = array();
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option($class) . ' nmr-datepicker';
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option('tabindex', 'signed_int', true);
    $atts['min'] = $tag->get_date_option('min');
    $atts['max'] = $tag->get_date_option('max');
    $atts['step'] = $tag->get_option('step', 'int', true);
    $atts['data-format'] = $tag->get_option('format', '', true);

    if ($tag->has_option('readonly')) {
        $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    }

    if ($tag->is_required()) {
        $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';
    }

    $atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';

    $value = (string) reset($tag->values);

    if (
        $tag->has_option('placeholder')
        or $tag->has_option('watermark')
    ) {
        $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
        $value = '';
    }

    $value = $tag->get_default_option($value);

    $value = wpcf7_get_hangover($tag->name, $value);

    $atts['value'] = $value;

    $atts['type'] = 'text';
    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts($atts);

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input %2$s />%3$s</span>',
        sanitize_html_class($tag->name),
        $atts,
        $validation_error
    );
    return $html;
}

function nmr_datepicker_enqueue_script() {   
    $path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', $path .'css/jquery-ui.css');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nmr_datepicker', $path . 'js/nmr-datepicker.js' , array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nmr_datepicker_enqueue_script');
```

[JS]

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".nmr-datepicker").each(function (i, item) {
            var settings = {};
            if (item.dataset.format) {
                settings.dateFormat = item.dataset.format;
            }
            if (item.id) {
                $(`#${item.id}`).datepicker(settings);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **$atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';**
```

I think the problem here is:-
`"$atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error"` -  taken as ternary argument

it should be:-

```
$atts['aria-invalid'] = ( $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false' );
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. Will check it asap and will update.